# PHP mail won't send when there is a URL in the body

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send this html email and for some reason it won't send when there's a link in the body.  The only difference between these two files seems to be that one has a link in the body.  If I put the same thing in the subject it sends fine.

Works perfectly:

```
//mail body and subject
$mail_body = "Test Email with no link.";
$subject = "Test email with no link";

//recipient
$recipient = "myemail@mydomain.com";

//headers to send HTML email
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
$header = $header . "Content-Type: text/html; charset="\iso-8859-1\"\n";
$header = $header . 'From: admin@test.com';

//send the message
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header) or die('mail could not be sent'); //mail command :)
echo('Good Test');
```

Does Not work:

```
//mail body and subject
$mail_body = "Test Email with link. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>";
$subject = "Test email with with link. ";

//recipient
$recipient = "myemail@mydomain.com";

//headers to send HTML email
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
$header = $header . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$header = $header . 'From: admin@test.com';

//send the message
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header) or die('mail could not be sent'); //mail command :)
echo('Bad Test');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quotes in your e-mail address. Check the backslashes:

```
$mail_body = "Test Email with link. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>";
```

Comment: Crud, I don't know why the backslashes didn't paste in, but they are in the code. It still does it with the backslashes in the code. I put them back in the example above but I fear it's too late and now everyone will think it was the common escaped backslash problem.  It's not.  Dang it, why didn't it paste those in.

Comment: Email address??? Did you mean to say "url" instead?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the href in your $mail_body has an unescaped double quote. Have you tried:

`$mail_body = "Test Email with link. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>";`

Note the backslashes.

Comment: Same goes for the Content-Type Header.

Comment: I added the backslashes to the example above.  They were in the code originally but for some reason didn't paste in here.  But yeah, it happens when they quotes are escaped.

Comment: ok, saw the fix. Just to be clear, is the script dying or is the email just not showing up/link not working?

Comment: Email is not showing up. I have determined that if the string "Http://" appears in the body, the email won't send.  Any other combo and it will send.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 quotes (") in the $mail_body tag - it tries to assign the information between the first 2 quotes only, then expects something like a semi colon (;) at the end or append operator (.), when it doesn't see one of these it doesn't know what to do. It also should be a problem in the 2nd header (`$header= $header . "Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-88598-1"\n";`

The simplest way to do this is:

Change the following:

FROM THIS:

`$mail_body = "Test Email with link. <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>";`

TO THIS:

`$mail_body = "Test Email with link. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>";`

FROM THIS: `$header = $header . "Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"\n";`
TO THIS: `$header = $header . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";`